# Symfony form generated an error when password is empty

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm building a password reset form. A user only has to type the password twice. I want to check it is min 8 chars long and not empty and both passwords are the same.

I use the following form type setting:

```
$builder
->add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
    'type' => PasswordType::class,
    'translation_domain' => 'validators',
    'invalid_message' => 'password_must_match',
    'required' => true,
    'constraints' => array(
        new NotBlank(),
        new Length(array('min' => 8)),
    )
 ))
->add('save', SubmitType::class);
```

The passwords must match and the min 8 chars checks works. Only when leaving the passwords empty, in the controller at line `$form->handleRequest($request)`; I get the following error:

> Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path
> "password".

I did try a lot of suggestion already like adding `'empty_data' => array()` and the `@Assert\NotBlank` in the entity.

Comment: have you tried `'empty_data' => ''` instead? because the data that is supposed to fall out of that form is supposed to be a string and not an array.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `User` entity has a method `setPassword(string $password)` with only `string` type hinting for the parameter.
On form submitting the symfony populates an entity by calling setter methods and it happens before validation.

In your case probably an error is thrown on form submiting `$form->handleRequest($request)` because in `$password` is `null` when called the `setPassword(string $password)` method

You should add the `null` type into `setPassword(?string $password)`